# unhandled exception Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

op_dc_ip_address_alloc:

Added vlan field in this table.
desc op_dc_ip_address_alloc;

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip_address     | char(40)            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| data_center_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pod_id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nic_id         | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reservation_id | char(40)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| taken          | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mac_address    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vlan           | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Host_pod_ref:

desc host_pod_ref;

```
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| id               | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL     |                |
| uuid             | varchar(40)         | YES  | UNI | NULL     |                |
| data_center_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL     |                |
| gateway          | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| cidr_address     | varchar(15)         | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| cidr_size        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| description      | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| allocation_state | varchar(32)         | NO   | MUL | Enabled  |                |
| external_dhcp    | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | 0        |                |
| removed          | datetime            | YES  | MUL | NULL     |                |
| owner            | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| created          | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| lastUpdated      | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL     |                |
| engine_state     | varchar(32)         | NO   |     | Disabled |                |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

These are two tables, i am trying to insert values in op_dc_ip_address_alloc as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `cloud`.`op_dc_ip_address_alloc` (ip_address, data_center_id, pod_id, mac_address)
    VALUES ('10.147.29.160', 1, 11, (select mac_address from `cloud`.`data_center` where id=1));
```

I am facing error as

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cloud`.`op_dc_ip_address_alloc`, CONSTRAINT `fk_op_dc_ip_address_alloc__pod_id` FOREIGN KEY (`pod_id`) REFERENCES `host_pod_ref` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: The value provided for insertion into `cloud.op_dc_ip_address_alloc` (it is 11) is absent in `host_pod_ref.id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO cloud.op_dc_ip_address_alloc (ip_address, data_center_id, pod_id, mac_address)
VALUES ('10.147.29.160', 1, 11, (select mac_address from clou``data_center where id=1));
```

Are you sure exist id=11 in the host_pod_ref table ?
I think this is the reason for the issue.